# why logs are not printed on console in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

why logs are not visible ?

I am using

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Logger } from "./logger";

Logger.configure({ ...Logger.defaultLoggerOptions, level: "debug" });
const logger = Logger.getLogger("vcw:app:api:user-service");

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<h1>Helo Vanil</h1>
<div>
  We u stathe saconfiguration as Parcel to bundle this sandbox, you can find more
  info about Parc
  <a href="https://parceljs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">here</a>.
</div>
`;
```

logger.info(`[sendOtpCode] email: nnee, method:hhh`);
logger.debug(`[sendOtpCode] email: nnee, method:hhh`);
logger.error(`[sendOtpCode] email: nnee, method:hhh`);

---

I configure logs like this

```
 Logger.configure({ ...Logger.defaultLoggerOptions, level: "debug" });
    const logger = Logger.getLogger("vcw:app:api:user-service");
```

**using like this**

```
logger.info(`[sendOtpCode] email: nnee, method:hhh`);
logger.debug(`[sendOtpCode] email: nnee, method:hhh`);
logger.error(`[sendOtpCode] email: nnee, method:hhh`);
```

[image]

I don't see any logs
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-danny-ko8pz1?file=/src/index.js

anything i am doing wrong

Comment: _"Console was cleared"_? Something is clearing your console, somewhere...

Comment: @Cerbrus did you see logs ?

Comment: hee is my code https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-danny-ko8pz1?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @Cerbrus anything i am doing wrong ..!!

Comment: Because your `Logger` class contains no code that logs to console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the debugger for that given namespace. Since you are targetting a browser you have to do:

```
window.localStorage.debug = "vcw:app:api:user-service";
```

This is mentioned in the [readme](https://github.com/debug-js/debug#browser-support)

[Example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-gagarin-pq76kq?file=/src/index.js) (note this might need a refresh to work)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in debug's readme on [Output Streams](https://github.com/debug-js/debug#output-streams)

> By default debug will log to stderr, however this can be configured per-namespace by overriding the log method:

If you want to see the logs in the browser console, set the namespace to log via `console .log`

```
log.log = console.log.bind(console); // don't forget to bind to console!
```

You can check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-mountain-q0jh06?file=/src/index.js).

Notice that I added `console.log.bind` in line 2

```
  constructor(namespace) {
    this.log = console.log.bind(console); //binded namespace to console
    this.namespace = namespace;
    if (namespace) {
      this.debugLog = _debug(namespace);
    }
```